# Java - How can I put canvases on top of each other using the OverlayLayout LayoutManager?

Tags: java, swing, awt, overlay

I want to put 2 Canvas objects on top op each other. Their backgrounds should be transparent (I did not address this yet). I want a simple way to work with Photoshop-like layers. I want to use as less Swing objects as possible.

I have a Container object that contains 2 canvases, which both draw a different line. I have attached an OverlayLayout LayoutManager to the container, which should overlay the canvases instead of putting them next to each other.

But my code only shows the first canvas. How can I get the second one to show up on top of the other one?

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.OverlayLayout;

public class Main {

    public Main() {
        // Create a window to draw into:
        Frame window = new Frame();
        window.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing (WindowEvent we) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        window.setSize(600,400);
        //
        // Create a Container for the MyCanvas instances:
        Container container = new Container();
        // Set the LayoutManager of the container:
        OverlayLayout layoutManager = new OverlayLayout(container);
        container.setLayout(layoutManager);
        //
        // Create 2 MyCanvas instances that each draw a line:
        MyCanvas canvas1 = new MyCanvas(75, 75);
        container.add(canvas1);
        MyCanvas canvas2 = new MyCanvas(135, 300);
        container.add(canvas2);
        //
        window.add(container);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main app = new Main();
    }   

    public class MyCanvas extends Canvas {

        int x2;
        int y2;

        public MyCanvas (int x2, int y2) {
            this.setSize(600,400);
            this.setLocation(0,0);
            this.x2 = x2;
            this.y2 = y2;
        }

        public void paint (Graphics g) {
            g.drawLine(0, 0, this.x2, this.y2);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Don't use "code snippet" when posting code. You highlight the code and click on the `{}` button. A comment is `//`. You don't need all the dashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the second one to show up on top of the other one?
>
> Their backgrounds should be transparent (I did not address this yet).

You have answered your own question. You need to make the top component transparent.

Don't use a Canvas for custom painting. Instead you can use a JPanel. Then you override the `paintComponent(...)` method to do the custom painting. And don't forget to invoke `super.paintComponent(...)` at the start of the method.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Then when you use a JPanel you make it transparent by using:

```
panel.setOpaque( false );
```

Also, you would generally use a JPanel as the container for the two custom painted panels.

When using the examples from the tutorial don't forget to copy the `invokeLater(...)` code so your GUI is created on the EDT. That is start with the working examples from the tutorial and then modify the examples to add your requirement so you have a better structured program than the code you just posted.

Comment: Thank you! The JPanel object and overriding it's paintComponent() method is what I needed!